# Fastest way to compare a string with an array of strings in C#2.0

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, comparison

What is the fastest way to compare a string with an array of strings in C#2.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mean to see if the string is in the array?  I can't remember if arrays support the .Contains() method, so if not, create a List< string >, add your array to the list via AddRange(), then call list.Contains({string to compare}).  Will return a boolean value indicating whether or not the string is in the array.

Comment: Correct, in 2.0 you would have to do `(new List<String>(array)).Contains(targetString);` - but from 3.5 you have the IEnumerable<String>.Contains extension method, so it's available for arrays also.

Comment: In 2.0, you can check whether the array contains a specific value or not with a simple `Array.IndexOf(arr, val) >= 0`.

Answer (score 32):

What kind of comparison do you want? Do you want to know if the given string is in the array?

```
bool targetStringInArray = array.Contains(targetString);
```

do you want an array of comparison values (positive, negative, zero)?

```
var comparisons = array.Select(x => targetString.CompareTo(x));
```

If you're checking for containment (i.e. the first option) and you're going to do this with multiple strings, it would probably be better to build a `HashSet<string>` from the array:

```
var stringSet = new HashSet<string>(array);

if (stringSet.Contains(firstString))  ...
if (stringSet.Contains(secondString)) ...
if (stringSet.Contains(thirdString))  ...
if (stringSet.Contains(fourthString)) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing this many times with a single array, you should sort the array and binary search it:

```
Array.Sort(array);
int index = Array.BinarySearch(array, input);
// if (index < 0) 
//      does not exists, "items > ~index" are larger and "< ~index" are smaller
// otherwise, "items > index" are larger and "< index" are smaller.
```

Otherwise just check the whole array naively:

```
bool exists = Array.IndexOf(array, input) >= 0;
```

Comment: If you're going to do it many times, there are more efficient searches than a binary search (assuming it's reasonably large, anyway). I'd go for something hash-based, e.g. HashSet.

Comment: Yep. The hash table/binary search tree debate... Both are better than searching the whole array, nevertheless. HashSet is only available in 3.5 though.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement to see if one list is a part of another, then you can use Contains().

Lets say

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>(){"1", "2"};
List<string> list2 = new List<string>(){"1", "2", "3"};

list2.Contains(list1) //will be True, but not vice versa.
```

That said, if you want to know not partial match, but exact match, you can do use Except(), and check for remainder.

```
if(list2.Except(list1).Length == 0) //will return false.
```

Answer (score -1):

//get data in list from source
                List checklist = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(x => x.ToLower().EndsWith("apk")).ToList();

```
            //get date from a text file
           List<string>  ls = ReadFile();

            foreach(string file in checklist)
            {
                //get file name
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(file);

                string TargetLocation = Path.Combine(TargetPath, filename);

                //now compare single string to a list 
                //it give in true and false 
                if(ls.Contains(filename)) 
                {
                    //do your task
                    //File.Copy(file, TargetLocation);
                }
            }
```